# Observing Magento 2 events in JavaScript

Tags: magento2, event-observer, knockoutjs

Magento 2 emmits a `catalog_product_compare_add_product` event whenever you add a product to the comparison list, which ultimately renders a "You added product %1 to the comparison list." message block.

How would you set up an observer in JavaScript that executes a JavaScript function whenever this event is emmitted? I'm aware you can do this by overriding `\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\Compare\Add`, but I would prefer not doing this if there's another way that doesn't involve overriding a core controller.

**UPDATE:**

I noticed this code in `vendor/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/compare/link.phtml`:

```
<li class="item link compare" data-bind="scope: 'compareProducts'" data-role="compare-products-link">
    <a class="action compare no-display" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Compare Products') ?>"
       data-bind="attr: {'href': compareProducts().listUrl}, css: {'no-display': !compareProducts().count}"
    >
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Compare Products') ?>
        <span class="counter qty" data-bind="text: compareProducts().countCaption"></span>
    </a>
</li>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{"[data-role=compare-products-link]": {"Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>}}
</script>
```

Since a "Compare Products *n* items" link will always be rendered whenever you add something to the comparison list, I guess the better question would be, how do I monitor this `<li>` via KnockoutJS so that I can execute my own JavaScript whenever the link is inserted into the `<li>` (without using a generic DOM mutation observer)?

**UPDATE 2:**

For now I have come up with a simple solution using KnockoutJS's containerless control flow that I'm somewhat satisfied with:

```
<li class="item link compare" data-bind="scope: 'compareProducts'" data-role="compare-products-link">
    <a class="action compare no-display" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Compare Products') ?>"
       data-bind="attr: {'href': compareProducts().listUrl}, css: {'no-display': !compareProducts().count}"
    >
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Compare Products') ?>
        (<span class="counter qty" data-bind="text: compareProducts().countCaption"></span>)
    </a>

    <!-- ko if: compareProducts().count -->
    <script>
    // Do something here when "You added product %1 to the comparison list."
    // message block is displayed
    </script>
    <!-- /ko -->

</li>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{"[data-role=compare-products-link]": {"Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>}}
</script>
```

The reason I'm not 100% satisfied is because I have to rely on `setInterval()` (and `clearInterval()` to implement a timeout) to detect when the message block is displayed. If someone can come up with a solution using a true event handler in JavaScript/KnockoutJS that is only triggered when a product is added to the comparison list, then I will accept that as the answer.

Comment: using a plugin or event observer is not  "overriding a core controller" , you can go with that approch

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar thanks, but is there a solution using just KnockoutJS? I just updated my question.